# Как в pytest/unittest прогнать один тест несколько раз

Tags: python, юнит-тесты, pytest

пишу тесты на python , и хотел узнать как прогнать один тест несколько раз? На pytest нужно для того чтобы все тесты выглядели/ запускались одинаково. Можно и на unittest чтобы понять. @pytest.mark.parametrize тоже использовать для вида не особо хочется.

Т.е. есть класс в setup_class идёт настройка, далее в классе присутствует 5 тестов(разных) и они прогоняются. Но как сделать настройку чтобы эти тесты( включая setup_class )прогонялись 10 раз?

Comment: ответ зависит от того, почему вы думаете вам нужно запускать unit test более одного раза.

Comment: @jfs, я уже перегнал на pytest с помощью parametrize. Мой тест при старте генерит входные данные. Сделанное для того чтобы тесты каждый раз были 'уникальными'( Макс разных случаев 128 - так что они повторяются). В parametrize просто добавил цикл с ransom и все ок. Но все равно интересно, можно ли тест запихнуть в цикл. Т.е. не внутри теста поставить цикл, а именно сам тест пихнуть в цикл. Не спорю - и то и то, лютое сумасшествие.

Comment: если вы хотите запустить  один и тот же тест с разными входными данными, то parametrize как раз именно для этого и подходит.

Comment: @jfs. Да, я понимаю. Но хотел попробовать запустить без аргументов несколько раз один тест. Да , это очень странное решение. Как вариант можно наговнокодить - сделать фейковый параметр и несколько раз добавить в parametrize.

Comment: Есть плагин [`pytest-repeat`](https://pypi.org/project/pytest-repeat/)

Comment: @jfs, а если необходимо в parametrize добавить 3 параметра для проверки, но прогнать нужно 200 раз? т.к. запрос происходит в базу и надо сравнить две базы на изменение параметров. как в таком случае сделать и избежать копипаста?